# How should I test that autoloads work properly with package.el?

Tags: package, use-package, autoload

I've added some autoloads to PACKAGE with the `;;;###autoload` cookie and I've run `M-x update-directory-autoloads` which generated `PACKAGE-autoloads.el`.  I have the following form in my init:

```el
(package-initialize)

;; ...
;; some stuff that needs package.el to be initialized
;; ...

(use-package PACKAGE
  :init nil
  :load-path "~/path/to/PACKAGE"
  :defer t)
```

What can I use as the `:init` form to load the autoloads as package.el would?  I'm assuming package.el loads the autoloads for every directory in `load-path` upon activation and before each package is `require`'d, but perhaps this is in an incorrect assumption.  This excerpt from `package.el` is what leads me to believe this is so:

```el
;; At activation time we will set up the load-path and the info path,
;; and we will load the package's autoloads.  If a package's
;; dependencies are not available, we will not activate that package.

;; Conceptually a package has multiple state transitions:
;;
;; * Download.  Fetching the package from ELPA.
;; * Install.  Untar the package, or write the .el file, into
;;   ~/.emacs.d/elpa/ directory.
;; * Autoload generation.
;; * Byte compile.  Currently this phase is done during install,
;;   but we may change this.
;; * Activate.  Evaluate the autoloads for the package to make it
;;   available to the user.
;; * Load.  Actually load the package and run some code from it.
```

Comment: If you are trying to emulate `package.el`, why not just place your `PACKAGE` in `package-user-dir` instead and have `package.el` activate it along with all your other packages for you?

Answer (score 3):

> What can I use as the `:init` form to load the autoloads as `package.el` would?

```el
(with-demoted-errors "Error loading autoloads: %s"
  (load "~/path/to/PACKAGE/PACKAGE-autoloads" nil t))
```

Refer to the function [`package--activate-autoloads-and-load-path`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el#n661).

> I'm assuming `package.el` loads the autoloads for every directory in `load-path` upon activation and before each package is `require`'d, but perhaps this is in an incorrect assumption.

`package.el` does indeed go through various directories loading autoloads files, but these directories are determined by `package-user-dir` and `package-directory-list`, not `load-path`. In fact, `package.el` updates `load-path` as it goes along; otherwise the autoloads loaded wouldn't work when invoked.

The autoloads of built-in packages are handled when Emacs is built/installed, and are already loaded on startup, even without `package-initialize`. Keep in mind that `package.el` is a package manager for external packages, not those which ship with Emacs proper.